# Choosing an appropriate sequence of $\{1,2,3\}$

Tags: fractals

Let $f_1,f_2,f_3$ be the contracting maps $f_i:x\mapsto \frac{1}{2}(x+p_i)$ from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to itself and $p_i\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Denoted by $S$ the attractor Sierpinki gastek of the iterated function system $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. I want to prove the following

> Given a point $a\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a sequence $k_n$ of elements $\{1,2,3\}$, we define $x_0=a$ and $x_{n+1}=f_{k_n}(x_n)$. Then
>
> (1) Each accumulation point of $\{x_n\}$ belongs to $S$
>
> (2) For each point $x\in S$ there exist a sequence $k_n$ such that $\{x_n\}$ has $x$ as an accumulation point.
>
> (3) There exist a point $a$ and a sequence $k_n$ such that every point in $S$ is an accumulation point of $\{x_n\}$

I have solved just $(1)$. All this properties should be a consequence of the fixed point's Theorem for contractions and the fact that the function
$$A\mapsto \bigcup_{i=1}^3 f[A]$$
is a contraction in the hyperspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ -the space of all non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Hausdorff metric.

I have solved (1) using this theorem and finding a sequence in $S$ that behaves "identically" to the sequence $\{x_n\}$ -meaning that i find a sequence $y_n\in S$ such that $|y_n-x_n|<\epsilon$ for an appropriate $n$ and every $\epsilon>0$.

I get stuck with the other ones. I have try several ways to solve this others two problem but I do not find how to satisfy the property of $\{x_n\}$. Intuitively, I have to find how the initial point "walks" to the point $x$ (point $(2)$) but I do not find the appropriate sequence. Any hint?

For $(3)$ the situation it is even more estrange because I should find a point and a sequence in such way that the point "walks everywhere" on $S$.I am pretty sure that the initial point is whatever point in $S$. How can I prove it?

These are classic results above self similar sets and they are really important to understand the very nature of a lot examples of fractals. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: A solid understanding of how the points of an attractor of an IFS can be "addressed" makes this problem relatively easy. Such addresses are described in the context of the Koch curve in the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369754/).

Comment: I know that properties but I did not find exactly what to do with them. Can you expand your comment?

Comment: Now,  I am truly understanding the meaning of "a solid understanding". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will call $E$ the set of nonempty compact subset of $\Bbb R^2$.
If $x \in \Bbb R^2$ and $Y \in E$, we define the distance from $x$ to $Y$ by $d_x(Y) = \min_{y \in Y} ||x-y||$. Since $Y$ is compact this actually is a minimum, and $d_x(Y) = 0 \iff x \in Y$.

Then the Hausdorff metric on $E$ is defined by $d(X,Y) = \max(\max_{x \in X} d_x(Y) ; \max_{y \in Y} d_y(X))$.

Note that forall $x \in \Bbb R^2$, $d_x : E \to \Bbb R$ is continuous (more precisely, $|d_x(Y)-d_x(Z)| \le d(Y,Z)$).

---

let $\phi : E \to E$ defined by $\phi(A) = \bigcup f_i[A]$. As you have noted, $\phi$ is a contraction ($d(\phi(X),\phi(Y)) \le \frac 12 d(X,Y)$) and has a unique fixpoint $S \in E$, and forall $A \in E$, $\phi^{\circ n}(A) \to S$

To prove $(1)$, we pick $A = \{a\}$. Then $A_n$ is the finite set of all possible images of $a$ after $n$ applications of some $f_i$, so it's all the possible values of $x_n$.
Suppose $y$ is an accumulation point of such a sequence $(x_n)$. Then there exists a sequence $(n_i)$ such that $||x_{n_i} - y || \to 0$, and since $x_{n_i} \in \phi^{\circ n_i}(A)$, we have $d_y(\phi^{\circ n_i}(A)) \le ||y-x_{n_i}||$, thus $d_y(\phi^{\circ n_i}(A)) \to 0$.
Since $d_y$ is continuous and $\phi^{\circ n_i}(A) \to S$, we get $d_y(S) = 0$, and therefore $y \in S$.

---

On to proving $(2)$ and $(3)$ ($a$ can in fact be any point).

First we see that forall $y \in S, \varepsilon > 0, x \in \Bbb R^2$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ and $x' \in \phi^{\circ n}(\{x\})$ such that $||x' - y || < \epsilon$ (we just have to pick $n$ such that $d(\phi^{\circ n}(\{x\}),S) \le \epsilon$). Put another way, there always exists a finite sequence of moves that brings $x$ to a point $x'$ within $\epsilon$ of $y$.

To prove $(2)$ we apply this repeatedly with a fixed $y \in S$ and $\epsilon = 1,1/2,1/3,\ldots$. From any $a$ there is a finite sequence that brings $a$ to $a_1$ such that $||a_1-y|| \le 1$, then there is a finite sequence that brings $a_1$ to $a_2$ such that $||a_2-y|| \le 1/2$, and so on.

To prove $(3)$ we do the same thing but instead of focusing on a particular $y$, we try to get within $\epsilon$ of everyone in $S$ before replacing $\epsilon$ with a smaller value.

Since $S$ is compact, forall $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite subset $S_\epsilon \subset S$ such that $d(S_\epsilon,S) \le \epsilon/2$.
From any point $a \in \Bbb R^2$ we can build a finite sequence of moves from $a$ such that the sequence obtained gets within $\epsilon/2$ of each point of $S_\epsilon$.
This is enough for that finite sequence to get within $\epsilon$ of any point in $S$.

Once again we repeat this for $\epsilon = 1,1/2,1/3,\ldots$ to build an infinite sequence of moves that gets arbitrarily close to any element of $S$.

Comment: Why do the others vote your answer down?

Comment: How can you assure that there is a finite sequence that brings $a_1$ to $a_2$?

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted, they didn't leave any comment and I don't think there is anything obviously wrong (or wrong at all). for any point $x$, any $\epsilon >0$, and any $y \in S$  there is a finite sequence that brings it to a point within $\epsilon$ of $y$. Since $a_1$ is a point, $1/2 > 0$ and $y \in S$ there is a finite sequence that brings $a_1$ to some point $a_2$ within $1/2$ of $y$. The concatenation of all those finite sequences gives you an infinite sequence that brings $a_1$ arbitrarily close to $y$, so $y$ is an accumulation point for that sequence.

Comment: **Justify your downvotes! **